# Symfony2 Prod / blank page : "Unable to load class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager"

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I'm facing an issue in PROD with my Symfony2 project, and I got a Blank page,  I tried stuff like cache:clear --env=prod, updating with composer, setting up Permissions for app/cache & app/logs but it does not work at all, I still got a blank page.

My Symfony/logs are clean, but here is my nginx error.log file :

```
2014/01/03 13:31:06 [error] 22357#0: *28014 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Unable to load class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager"' in /var/www/mysfproject/myfolder/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassCollectionLoader.php:259
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/mysfproject/myfolder/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassCollectionLoader.php(98): Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ClassCollectionLoader::getOrderedClasses(Array)
#1 /var/www/mysfproject/myfolder/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2375): Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ClassCollectionLoader::load(Array, '/var/www/epipor...', 'classes', true, false, '.php')
#2 /var/www/mysfproject/myfolder/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2211): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->doLoadClassCache('classes', '.php')
#3 /var/www/mysfproject/myfolder/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2245): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
#4 /var/www/mysfproject/myfolder/web/app.php(23): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handl" while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "mywebsite.com", referrer: "https://www.google.fr/"
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: can you post the contents of your `web/app.php` and `app/AppKernel.php`?

Comment: web/app.php : [link](https://gist.github.com/Dsensei/8238131) & app/AppKernel.php : [link](https://gist.github.com/Dsensei/8238054)

Comment: Edit app.php and set debug = true. $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);  That should at least give you a better error message.

Comment: I just changed debug to true but it still displays a blank page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally resolved my problem !

I only restarted nginx & php5-fpm !

```
service nginx restart
service php5-fpm restart
```

Hope this will help !

Comment: This happens to my application all the time, and the resolution is always the same: restart apache. This usually happens when my web application is experiencing traffic and then bootstrap.php.cache simple just fails in the loadClass() function. Quite frankly, it's ridiculous why symfony2 works like this.